# unresolved identifier in mapkit

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, mkannotation

The following code was the same question on stack overflow. However it looks like the code was in swift 2. I added a image jj for some of the code but I am getting 1 error message. The error message is `var anView = thisMAP.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId )`. The error message states that **reuseId is a unresolved identifier** That is the only error message. If that is fixed the code will compile.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class Annotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation
{
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
var custom_image: Bool = true
var color: MKPinAnnotationColor = MKPinAnnotationColor.purple
}
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet var thisMAP: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.thisMAP.delegate = self;

    let annotation = Annotation()
    thisMAP.addAnnotation(annotation)

    let annotation2 = Annotation()
    annotation2.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 1.0)
    annotation2.custom_image = false
    thisMAP.addAnnotation(annotation2)

    let annotation3 = Annotation()
    annotation3.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 1.0, longitude:  0.0)
    annotation3.custom_image = false
    annotation3.color = MKPinAnnotationColor.green
    thisMAP.addAnnotation(annotation3)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if (annotation is MKUserLocation) {
        return nil
    }

    var anView = thisMAP.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId )

    if anView == nil {
        if let anAnnotation = annotation as? Annotation {
            if anAnnotation.custom_image {
                let reuseId = "jj.png"
                anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                anView.image = UIImage(named:"jj.png")
            }
            else {
                let reuseId = "pin"
                let pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                pinView.pinColor = anAnnotation.color
                anView = pinView
            }
        }
        anView.canShowCallout = false
    }
    else {
        anView.annotation = annotation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line the reuseID is not known at this place - only inside the `if-else` blocks thats why it is the error `reuseId is a unresolved identifier`:

```
    var anView = thisMAP.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId )
```

you can only use it inside the scope where it is defined.

place the definition of `reuseID` before this line!

it should be the same as your `reuseId` you defined in the `if anAnnotation.custom_image {`

Comment: what would define reuselID as?